# Create package with cython so users can install it without having cython already installed

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I have a question. I would like to distribute my cython-powered packages, but I see no easy way to build them in setup.py. I would like setup.py to:

- most importantly: install my package without cython (from pre-generated C files or by installing cython beforehand)
- rebuild (run cythonize) package on sdist
- not need to hard-code list of my cython modules (just use glob or something)
- be able to work without .c files (should not be stored in git) or .pyx (might not be distributed). at least one of those sets will be always present of course.

Currently in my itchy package, I am using this quite complicated code:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist as _sdist
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.core import Extension



def generate_extensions():
    return [
        # Compile cython-generated .c files into importable .so libraries.
        Extension(os.path.splitext(name)[0], [name])
        for name in C_FILES
    ]


# In distribution version, there are no pyx files, when you clone package from git, there will be no c files.
CYTHON_FILES = glob('itchy/*.pyx')
C_FILES = glob('itchy/*.c')
extensions = generate_extensions()


class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def run(self):
        # Compile cython files (.pyx, some of the .py) into .c files if Cython is available.
        try:
            from Cython.Build import cythonize
            if CYTHON_FILES:
                cythonize(CYTHON_FILES)

                # Update C_FILES in case they were originally missing.
                global C_FILES, extensions
                C_FILES = glob('itchy/*.c')
                extensions = generate_extensions()
            else:
                print('No .pyx files found, building extensions skipped. Pre-built versions will be used.')
        except ImportError:
            print('Cython is not installed, building extensions skipped. Pre-built versions will be used.')
            assert C_FILES, 'C files have to be present in distribution or Cython has to be installed'
        _build_ext.run(self)


class sdist(_sdist):
    def run(self):
        # Make sure the compiled Cython files in the distribution are up-to-date
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        _sdist.run(self)


setup(
    (...)
    ext_modules = extensions,
    cmdclass = {
        'build_ext': build_ext,
        'sdist': sdist,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually done by attempting to import cython and adjusting extensions to either

1. Build pyx files with cython if cython is present
2. Build C files if cython is not present

For example:

```
try:
    from Cython.Distutils.extension import Extension
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
except ImportError:
    from setuptools import Extension
    USING_CYTHON = False
else:
    USING_CYTHON = True

ext = 'pyx' if USING_CYTHON else 'c'
sources = glob('my_module/*.%s' % (ext,))
extensions = [
    Extension(source.split('.')[0].replace(os.path.sep, '.'),
              sources=[source],
    )
for source in sources]
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext} if USING_CYTHON else {}

setup(<..>, ext_modules=extensions, cmdclass=cmdclass)
```

The `source.split` stuff is needed as cythonized extension names need to be in the form `my_module.ext` while glob requires path names like `my_module/ext`.

[See this repository](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/ssh2-python/blob/master/setup.py#L14-L25) for a real-world example.

You should, however, include `.c` files in your git repo as well as the distributable otherwise when it comes time to build a distribution the `.c` files will be re-built and may or may not be the same files as were built on your machine.

They may be built by another version of cython, for example, or on a different platform, producing different code.

Cython is a static compiler - it's recommended to commit the files it produces to repository.

> It is strongly recommended that you distribute the generated .c files as well as your Cython sources, so that users can install your module without needing to have Cython available.

[See Cython documentation on distributing modules](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This quite easily solves most of the problems. 

However, it would require me to distribute .pyx files just in case the user installing my package has Cython already installed. Also if I forgot to run build_ext before sdist, the created package wouldn't be up to date.

Comment: It is generally recommended to ship both, yes. Another approach would be to require an env variable to enable building with Cython and default to building C files otherwise. That would negate having to distribute pyx files. The last comment reinforces why C files should be in repo - creating a distribution should never depend on having to generate something that is not in the repository.

Comment: Can you add `cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext} if USING_CYTHON else {}` to your example code? After that, it works nicely :)

(also I prefer `Extension(file_name.split('.')[0].replace(os.path.sep, '.'), sources=[file_name]) for file_name in sources` and cythonize import is not needed)

Comment: I disagree that it’s a good idea to store the cython generated C files in your repo, especially if the cython code changes often. Instead, you can make it so that .c files get included in your source distribution when you make a release, but still mandate that developers generate the C files from cython if they’re building the project from a repo. That way you avoid constant code churn in auto generated files.

Comment: Distributing source code files that are not subject to revision control is a major no-no. Especially since there are many ways to get different C files generated than what were used for testing, eg by different cython versions being used or the cython compilation happening on a different platform. See [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=compilation#distributing-cython-modules).

Comment: To me, including the C files in the repo seems contrary to the goal of ensuring consistent builds.  It would introduce a second source of truth and would prevent having a centralized automated build environment, since part of the build would be manual and on the developer's machine, so the full build environment would be dependent on whoever made the last commit.

Comment: @lehiester If the source files are being re-generated on the fly, how does that ensure consistent builds? The point of committing statically generated files into source control is precisely to ensure consistent builds. Yes, it is the developer's job to do this, like with any other code changes.

Comment: Assuming that compilation on the same machine with the same toolchain and the same exact configuration is a deterministic process, it would always yield the same result.  If it's nondeterministic then consistent builds are impossible under any circumstances.  But if e.g. it's possible that some compilation options might break the build, then that's much more difficult to ensure consistency--all of the configuration on each dev's machine needs to be ensured to be exactly the same because their machine is now part of the compilation process.

Comment: So many assumptions.. The official documentation, best practice, real world use cases and common sense all disagree. That said, do as you wish.

Comment: In this case, the generated C files are not actually source code, as they are not the source of the target (the .pyx files are the source). If you wanted the user to have the same compiled targets, then you should distribute the targets (eg as wheels)

Comment: @danny I imagine in your C projects you commit all the generated assembly code then, right? Otherwise how can you guarantee consistent builds if a developer switches between gcc/icc/clang? If this sounds silly, the same can be said about your suggestion of committing the generated C files in a Cython project. The official documentation actually recommends *distributing* the C files: that means in the source distribution on PyPI. It does't say that you should put the generated C files in the git repository, as that is simply a bad idea.