# Cython generated c/cpp files in poetry sdist tar.gz for no-cython-installation

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

I use Poetry to build tar.gz. and .whl of my package. Cython docs recommend to distribute cython generated c files along with pyx ones. http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules

What should I add to `build.py` or `pyproject.toml` to generate c/cpp files by calling `poetry build` and `poetry build -f sdist`?

I tried this (from [Create package with cython so users can install it without having cython already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784964/create-package-with-cython-so-users-can-install-it-without-having-cython-already)):

build.py:

```
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
from setuptools.command.sdist import sdist as _sdist
...
class sdist(_sdist):
    def run(self):
        # Make sure the compiled Cython files in the distribution are up-to-date
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        _sdist.run(self)

def build(setup_kwargs):
    setup_kwargs.update({
        ...
        'cmdclass': {'sdist': sdist,
                     'build_ext': build_ext}
    })
```

Not worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of `poetry` (1.0.5) ignores custom `build.py` when building an sdist, so there's no chance without modifying `poetry` first. In the meantime, you can use third-party projects like [`taskipy`](https://pypi.org/project/taskipy/) to replace the `poetry build` command with a custom one, e.g.

```toml
# pyproject.toml

...

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
cython = "^0.29.15"
taskipy = "^1.1.3"

[tool.taskipy.tasks]
sdist = "cython fib.pyx && poetry build -f sdist"

...
```

and execute `poetry run task sdist` instead of `poetry build -f sdist`.

Comment: thanks. Is it also possible to run `build_ext` somehow? I'd like to build binaries, run tests and then remove them

Comment: There are many ways to do that, from writing a custom script and executing it in the `taskipy` test command, to building and cleaning up directly in the test code - depending on the test framework you use, the code will look different. If you want the latter, I suggest to create a separate question where you describe the test stack you are using.